# How to disable auto refresh property of browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

For example, after loading page i got disconected from the internet and when internet reconnects, can i stop the browser to refresh the page with the help of jquery/javascript?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? I guess the answer of your question is no, btw.

Comment: Which browsers refresh the page when the network connections are enable?

Comment: i am just asking for yes no ans and if yes how? nothing much

Comment: I think browsers do not refresh pages automatically. Some pages, however, may have to code to periodically reload itself using javascript / headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which may help if the problem is in your browser, or if there is some other problem please explain in brief:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-web-page-auto-refresh-for-various-browsers/

Comment: @NirojAdhikary in this case, pls share your solution here and accept it as an answer to your own question, so you can help other people

Comment: @Niroj Adhikary pls post your solution as an answer to your questio for other who have the same problem